I'm using React Navigation. How can I make it so that when I use TopTabs, for example "Products" my titles in TopTabs change?
It's just part of my project.
1.MainScreen.tsx
import NavigationTab from '../components/navigation/NavigationTab';
import { tabs } from './navigation/NavigationScreens';

const MainScreen = () => {
  return NavigationTab(tabs);
};

export default MainScreen;


NavigationScreens.tsx

import NavigationStack from '../../components/navigation/NavigationStack';
import { NavigationTabProps, NavigationTopTabsProps } from '../../interfaces/Navigation';
import { FavoriteScreen } from '../authorized/FavoriteScreen';
import { GoodsScreen } from '../authorized/GoodsScreen';
import { HomeScreen } from '../authorized/HomeScreen';
import { PositionsScreen } from '../authorized/PositionsScreen';
import { SearchScreen } from '../authorized/SearchScreen';
import ServicesScreen from '../authorized/ServicesScreen';

const topTabs: NavigationTopTabsProps[] = [
  {
    name: 'Услуги',
    component: ServicesScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Товары',
    component: GoodsScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Позиции',
    component: PositionsScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Недвижимость',
    component: HomeScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Транспорт',
    component: SearchScreen,
  },
];

const tabs: NavigationTabProps[] = [
  {
    name: 'Главная',
    focusedIcon: 'home',
    component: HomeScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Категории',
    focusedIcon: 'border-all',
    component: NavigationStack,
  },
  {
    name: 'Избранное',
    focusedIcon: 'star',
    component: FavoriteScreen,
  },
  {
    name: 'Поиск',
    focusedIcon: 'text-search',
    component: SearchScreen,
  },
];
export { topTabs, tabs };


NavigationStack.tsx

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import NavigationDrawer from './NavigationDrawer';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const NavigationStack = function () {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="NavigationDrawer" component={NavigationDrawer} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
export default NavigationStack;

4.NavigationDrawer.tsx
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import NavigationTopTabs from './NavigationTopTab';
import { topTabs } from '../../screens/navigation/NavigationScreens';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const NavigationDrawer = function () {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Назад"
        component={NavigationTopTabs}
        options={{
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          headerTitle: 'Разделы',
        }}
      />
      {topTabs.map((screen) => (
        <Drawer.Screen
          key={screen.name}
          name={screen.name}
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
          }}
        >
          {(props) => <screen.component {...props} />}
        </Drawer.Screen>
      ))}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default NavigationDrawer;


TopTabs.tsx

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { topTabs } from '../../screens/navigation/NavigationScreens';

const TopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const NavigationTopTabs = function () {
  return (
    <TopTabs.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          textTransform: 'capitalize',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
      }}
    >
      {topTabs.map((screen) => (
        <TopTabs.Screen key={screen.name} name={screen.name}>
          {(props) => <screen.component {...props} />}
        </TopTabs.Screen>
      ))}
    </TopTabs.Navigator>
  );
};
export default NavigationTopTabs;



GoodsScreen.tsx

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import ServicesScreen from './ServicesScreen';

const TopTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
export function GoodsScreen() {
  return (
    <TopTabs.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          textTransform: 'capitalize',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
      }}
    >
      <TopTabs.Screen name="Автомобильные" component={ServicesScreen} />
      <TopTabs.Screen name="Мобильные" component={ServicesScreen} />
    </TopTabs.Navigator>
  );
}

Example:
"Services, Goods, Items, Real Estate."
I select "Goods,"
and TopTabs changes to
"Automotive, Mobile, Appliances."
I'm not very familiar with Hooky's, but it's likely their implementation will help

You can change dynamically your header title with the navigation property.
And to get the navigation property you either pass it via props or using the hook useNavigation().
And to change the header title you just need to do:
navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Your custom title' })} 

See navigation property documentation for more detail.
